# Add multiple values to a datalayer variable based on url

Tags: javascript

I try to use a `custome variable` in google tag manage in order to count how many users saw a material.

I have four different materials in which users come from different paths of site. The only option I have to separate them is using there url because for every material in url I have this format:

```
example.com/material1 
example.com/material2
example.com/material3
example.com/material4
```

What datalayer should I use in order to have one variable named material but have four different values based on the previous links?

Comment: The values in this variable reference a view count for each "material"?

Answer (score 1):

If the information is already in the url you do not need a dataLayer variable at all. Go to "variable" in the menu  and in the "pages" section tick the box in front of "page path". Now you have the {{Page Path}} variable available which for your examples would contain /material1, /material2 etc.

If you want a total of the material views in Google Analytics you can either filter the all pages report by "path contains material" and look up the aggregate number, or you can create a custom metric that is incremented every time the page path contains /material.